# Find a row in a sheet using multiple criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sheet like this:
Each line is a  3 members-family record, and each column contains the name of the family member (father, mother, child)

```
COLUMN_A     COLUMN_B      COLUMN_C

 david         jane         john
 michael       jenny        kelly
 david         sarah        peter
 leo           kelly        peter
```

I want to find a record by specifying the name of the father, the mother and the child.

I was thinking to do a .Find on each column, but I am not sure how  to do it and also don't know if there is not a better ready made solution to search records like this.

Answer (score 0):

One method I've used in the past is to add each family combination into a Publicly declared dictionary object. Once added, a subsequent subroutine can search the Dictionary object for the match, and then interact with the row.

See the code below, and let me know if you can figure it out/ adapt it to your need.

```
Public oDictionary As Object

Public Sub CreateEntryList()
    Dim rngToAdd As Range
    Dim strKey As String

    Set rngToAdd = Sheet1.Range("A2:A5")
    Set oDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    For Each cel In rngToAdd
        strKey = cel.Value & cel.Offset(, 1).Value & cel.Offset(, 2).Value
        If Not oDictionary.exists(strKey) Then
            oDictionary.Add strKey, cel.Row
        End If
    Next cel
End Sub

Sub InteractWithFoundrow()
    Dim strSearch As String

    strSearch = Range("A3") & Range("B3") & Range("C3")

    If oDictionary.exists(strSearch) Then
        Rows(oDictionary(strSearch)).Interior.Color = vbRed
    Else
        MsgBox ("Error: Doesn't  exist")
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: Thanks to @user3561813 he informed me about a problem in the code. I have updated accordingly. It may not be really professional but it will do the work.

below code is a little bit simpler then @user3561813

Code assumes that your layout is like this:

[image]

```
Sub rowvscol()
Dim Father As String
Dim Mother As String
Dim Children As String
Dim rng As Range
Dim LastRow As Long

Father = Range("F2").Value
Mother = Range("G2").Value
Children = Range("H2").Value
LastRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
i = 1
While i <= LastRow
With Range("B" & i & ":B" & LastRow) '<- Father Column
    Set rng = .Find(What:=Father, _
        LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False)
        If Not rng Is Nothing And rng.Offset(0, 1).Value = Mother And rng.Offset(0, 2).Value = Children Then
            MsgBox rng.Row
            Exit Sub
        End If
End With
i = i + 1
Wend
MsgBox "No match"
End Sub
```

As a result it is popping up a msgbox which you can change regarding your code.

[image]

Comment: True, your version of the code is simpler, but it's also limited. It only searches for the first occurrence of father, then tests if wife and child match. If the father's name repeats multiple times, then the code returns False unless the request is coincidentally the first occurrence of the father. In fact, if father names didn't repeat, we wouldn't have to test the other columns at all, since father would be unique. We can use a `Loop` and the `FindNext` method, but with three columns, it could start to get ugly.

Comment: That is definately true. I missed that. Thank you very much for the information @user3561813 . What if we nest 2 more if's inside the current one to check mother and child?

Comment: Not a problem @Dubison. Yes, you can nest `IF` statements within the the search to check mother and child, but I think the code becomes a lot messier. First, we'd have to search for the Father. Next, check Mother. If Mother is incorrect, then `Loop` over the Fathers. If Mother is correct, then `Loop` over the children. I suspect that using these nested `Loop` and `IF` statements will be less efficient.

Comment: @user3561813 I have updated the code after your feedback. I have input a `while` loop with variable range `.find` . It looks it is working :) I think OP already lost his/her interest anyway. We are the only one's who is discussing now :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this without VBA with the following formula:

```
=INDEX(C:C,SUMPRODUCT((A:A="david")*(B:B="jane")*ROW(C:C)),0)
```

Substituting "david" and "jane" for cell references if needed.